# Is there exist a ball with lesser radius than another ball that contains it?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

If $B_1$ and $B_2$ are two balls in metric space $X$ with radius $r_1$ and $r_2$, respectively and $B_1‎\subseteq‎B_2$,Is it possible that $r_1>r_2$ ?

I think, it can occure in discrete metric space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : if the inclusion is not strict, yes.

$B(0,2) = B(0,3)$ with the discrete disttance